# Prevent users with Azure AD accounts to access my storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I would like to prevent people with managed identity from accessing my storage.

Please help me on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To prevent users with azure AD account try to disallow all public access to storage account while disable, any future anonymous requests to that account will fail your data will never be available for public access until a user with appropriate permissions

[To disallow public access for a storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal#allow-or-disallow-public-read-access-for-a-storage-account) , configure the account's [AllowBlobPublicAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-prevent#permissions-for-allowing-or-disallowing-public-access) property :

- ***Go to azure portal -> storage account -> setting - Find the Configuration ->  Set Blob public access – Disable***

After you update the public access setting for the storage account, it may take up to 30 second to  change is fully propagated

To check the anonymous requests of storage account, I suggest to use below steps:

- ***In azure portal-> under Monitoring -> click Metrics-> set the scope -> Metric Namespace as Blob -> Metric field as Transactions  ->  Aggregation field as Sum.***
- ***Next Add filter ->in filter ->set Authenticationin Property value -> equal sign (=) in Operator field and finally Values field as Anonymous***

After configuring the metrics, the unidentified access will appear in the graph and you can also configure alert rule for notification to prevent and security purpose [Create, view, and manage Metric Alerts Using Azure Monitor - Azure Monitor | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-metric)

For more information in detail, please **find** below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-prevent